# Angular 2 bootstrap 4 tabs with horizontal scrolling

Tags: angular, scroll, tabs, bootstrap-4

I'm looking for a way to display Bootstrap tabs when there are a lot of tabs. The default behavior with Bootstrap 4 is to let the overflow visible.

What I want is something like this:
http://home.golden.net/~tomescu/bootstrap-responsive-tabs/demo/

As you can see, it only displays the visibles tabs (to fit the tab bar), and the non visibles tabs are displayed in a dropdown. When you resize the page, the tabs are rearranged. 
When you click on a tabs from the dropdown menu, the clicked tab pop at the end of the navbar (end of displayed tabs).

I'm looking for that to works with Angular 2 and Bootstrap v4 (like a directive or a custom component).